# Incompatibility warning when referencing System.ComponentModel.Composition.Registration from .NET Core

Tags: .net-core

I'm getting this warning when indirectly referencing the Nuget package `System.ComponentModel.Composition.Registration` in my .NET Core 3.1 project. I'm not sure what's causing this or what do do about it.

```
Package 'System.ComponentModel.Composition.Registration 4.7.0' was restored using
 '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7,
 .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8'
 instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not
 be fully compatible with your project.
```

Comment: It turned out this only happened when packages were restored using `nuget.exe restore`. Switching to `dotnet restore` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue with System.Windows.Forms. Make sure the assembly reference is correct or try to install with `dotnet add package [yourpackagehere]`.

If this doesn't work, the answer to this question solved my issue: [Unable to resolve System.Windows.Forms.dll in .Net Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59890543/unable-to-resolve-system-windows-forms-dll-in-net-core-3-1)

Just put `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App" />` into your .csproj ItemGroup section.

I'm not entirely sure whether this would work or not but it's worth a try.

Hope that works!

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall this Composition.Registration if you don't need it. It's just not compatible with your new 3.1 project.

Comment: It is included through the package `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` 3.1.0 which is specifically designed for .NET Core. I need it to run the application as a Windows service.