# Unable to resolve System.Windows.Forms.dll in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-framework-version

I have a scenario where we are using a legacy .Net Framework dll in .Net core 3.1 class library. Internally .Net Framework dll is using System.Windows.Forms.dll which .Net core is not able to resolve.

I am getting below error message during runtime

*Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.*

In a ideal world there is no point in adding System.Windows.Forms.dll to a class library but is there any way to add System.Windows.Forms and its dependencies in .Net core class library.

*Note: I have tried manually adding System.Windows.Forms.dll but it did not work out.*

Comment: What do you mean "not able to resolve"? Can you edit your post to include the exact error message that you are seeing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I got the resolution, we can achieve this by framework reference.

```
<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App" />
```

For more details please refer https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2019/01/09/netcore-primitives-3/

Comment: I tried this approach with a .NET Core 3.1 Azure Function and it didn't help.

Comment: @Murphybro2 had you ever resolved this? If so, what was the solution? I am also facing problems with .NET Core 2.1 / 3.1 Azure functions

Comment: @JurgenCuschieri No unfortunately not. We decided it wasn't possible and had to change the spec. We were also trying to use a .dll in an Azure function that required Windows Forms.

Comment: If you want to use winforms dll in .net core 3.0.5 then you need to change is as below in your csproj file.                                                                               <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <UseWindowsForms>True</UseWindowsForms>      
    </PropertyGroup>

Answer (score 1):

It works with me in .net core 3.1 by adding `<UseWindowsForms>True</UseWindowsForms>` inside project .csproj file to become like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>True</UseWindowsForms>
</PropertyGroup>
```