# How do you create a Debugger Visualizer in VS 2019 for .netcore 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, debuggervisualizer

I have a debugger visualizer working for my NETFX 4.7.2 code.  I am porting it to .netcore 3.1.  I try to run the visualizer and I get the following error: Unable to load the custom visualizer

Additional information:
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I have tried porting the visualizer code to .netcore and I hit several problems using System.Windows.Form, using Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers no longer work and I don't know what reference to include.

I have looked around but I can't seem to find anything to guide me as to what to do to port my visualizer or get the existing one to work.  I'm hoping someone here can give me a thread to pull on.

### Thanks,

Comment: Ok so the windows forms issue I got around with help from this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59890543/unable-to-resolve-system-windows-forms-dll-in-net-core-3-1

Still trying to figure out the reference to VisualStudio.DebugerVisualizers  when I find out what the fix is there I'll bring it back here.

Comment: Is it just something obvious that I'm missing?  Just point me in the right direction if you can.  I can't seem to find answers on this any where.